# Querying scopes on joined object in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am not sure if this is possble in laravel as I have not seen an example but it would be helpful if it did.

Lets say I have a `User` and a `Post` object, the post has some complex logic for and active state which I would like to keep encapsulated in it.

```
class Post {
    static public scopeActive($query) {
        // Fuzzy logic for determining activity
    }
}
```

To Query users with a post I think I can do

```
User::whereHas('Post');
```

However I am lost on trying to extend this syntax to apply the Active scope, as this only applies to the post object.

I would like to query users with an active post.

Comment: I believe what you have described there is already correct. The query inside the closure passed to `whereHas` is the query for the related record (i.e. post), so the active scope will be applied to the post query. Have you tried it? If so, what didn't work?  Did you check the queries run using `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`?

Comment: You are right. I was confused by the docs. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
User::whereHas('Post', function($q)
    {
        $q->active();
    }
);
```

The docs only state that $q is 'the query' in fact it is a 'Post' Builder object which is great.

Also worth noting that this will not join on Post, only check for exsistance of a Post object with the query attributes given.